# I want to find the frequency of words in MapType by date in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I want to get the word frequency by date. But I am struggling.

[image]

I want these results

> date                                                         wordcount
>
> 2020-07-06                                          ["word1"->3,"word2"->2......]

```
keyword_f = dict_df.select("createDate","wordcount")
keyword_f = keyword_f.groupby("createDate").agg(flatten(collect_list("wordcount")).alias("keywords"))
keyword_f = keyword_f.withColumn("statistic_type",lit("keyword_f"))
keyword_f.show(100,False)
```

it is my code,  What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your original dataframe, this is better to get the count of the words.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, count, collect_list, map_from_arrays

df = spark.createDataFrame(words).toDF('createDate', 'nounwords')
df.show(10, False)

+----------+----------------+
|createDate|nounwords       |
+----------+----------------+
|2020-07-01|[]              |
|2020-07-01|[test]          |
|2020-07-01|[test, template]|
|2020-07-01|[aaa, bbb]      |
|2020-07-01|[test, ccc]     |
+----------+----------------+

df2 = df.select('createDate', explode('nounwords').alias('nounwords')) \
  .groupBy('createDate', 'nounwords') \
  .agg(count(col('nounwords')).alias('count'))
df2.show(10, False)

+----------+---------+-----+
|createDate|nounwords|count|
+----------+---------+-----+
|2020-07-01|bbb      |1    |
|2020-07-01|template |1    |
|2020-07-01|test     |3    |
|2020-07-01|ccc      |1    |
|2020-07-01|aaa      |1    |
+----------+---------+-----+

df3 = df2.groupBy('createDate') \
   .agg(collect_list(col('nounwords')).alias('nounwords'), collect_list(col('count')).alias('count')) \
   .withColumn('map', map_from_arrays(col('nounwords'), col('count'))) \
   .drop('nounwords', 'count')
df3.show(10, False)

+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|createDate|map                                                     |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-07-01|[bbb -> 1, template -> 1, test -> 3, ccc -> 1, aaa -> 1]|
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```